# Removing All Items From A ComboBox?

Tags: vba, combobox

How can I programmatically remove all items from a combobox in VBA?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to remove each one individually unfortunately:

```
       For i = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount

           'Remove an item from the ListBox using ListBox1.RemoveItem 
       Next i
```

Update - I don't know why my answer did not include the full solution:

```
For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 to 0 Step - 1 
        ListBox1.RemoveItem i 
Next i
```

Comment: Just pointing out (after struggling with it like an idiot) that you are removing the top item each time. If you try to make it `i` then you get a lovely out of bounds error about halfway through.

Comment: @PsychoData meaning that you can do `For i = ListBox1.ListCount to 1 Step -1` and it should work fine.

Comment: make that `For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 to 0  Step - 1 ListBox1.RemoveItem i Next`

Answer (score 33):

Psuedo code ahead (updated with actual code):

```
Do While ComboBox1.ListCount > 0
    ComboBox1.RemoveItem (0)
Loop
```

Basically, while you have items, remove the first item from the combobox.  Once all the items have been removed (count = 0), your box is blank.

Method 2:  Even better

```
ComboBox1.Clear
```

Comment: Sorry, VBA does not provide clear method for a combo box control.

Comment: @Sham Yemul: I can confirm ComboBox.Clear does indeed work, at least as of Excel 2010 on the ActiveX ComboBox control.

Comment: What version of excel are you using, because. Clear works for me in 2016.

Comment: Access ComboBox and ListBox do not have `.Clear` methods too (current Access 365 version), but `lst.RowSource = vbNullString` removes all items. Otherwise the `Do ... Loop` seems the most beautiful workaround to me.

Comment: Can also confirm the Microsoft 365 Access Combo Box does not support `Clear`. Throws a compile error: `Method or data member not found`.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way:

```
Combobox1.RowSource = ""  'Clear the list
Combobox1.Clear           'Clear the selected text
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ControlFormat method:

```
ComboBox1.ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems
```

Answer (score 4):

Best Way:

```
Combobox1.items.clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

For Access VBA, if a ComboBox has been populated with a Row Source Type of Value List, I find the following works:

```
ComboBox.RowSource = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

For Access VBA, which does not provide a .clear method on user form comboboxes, this solution works flawlessly for me:

```
   If cbxCombobox.ListCount > 0 Then
        For remloop = (cbxCombobox.ListCount - 1) To 0 Step -1
            cbxCombobox.RemoveItem (remloop)
        Next remloop
   End If
```

Comment: This method will only work when combobox source is set to valuelist

Answer (score 0):

In Access 2013 I've just tested this:

```
While ComboBox1.ListCount > 0
    ComboBox1.RemoveItem 0
Wend
```

Interestingly, if you set the item list in Properties, this is not lost when you exit Form View and go back to Design View.

Answer (score 0):

> me.Combobox1.Clear

This is the common method

Answer (score 0):

I could not get clear to work.  (Mac Excel)
but this does.

ActiveSheet.DropDowns("CollectionComboBox").RemoveAllItems

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply remove the value in the combo box:

`me.combobox = ""`

If you want to remove the recordset of the combobox, the easiest way is:

```
me.combobox.recordset = ""
me.combobox.requery
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
    ComboBox1.Value = Null
    ComboBox2.Value = Null
End Sub
```