# Create a dropdown box that contains numbers equal to or less than a number in another field

Tags: database, ms-access, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am creating a database in Access 2013 for a library that has multiple copies of different books. I want to create a combo box/lookup list that displays numbers equal to or less than the total available copies of the book so that when a book is issued the librarian can select the next lowest value in the drop down. ( the number of available copies decreases by one). The number of purchased copies may change as the library buys more copies of the more popular books and so the drop down box needs to dynamically update. How do I do this? Do I need a replationship?

Comment: This sounds like redundant data. I assume you will also create a record for the lending (issue)? Then the number of available books could be calculated.

Comment: I do have a table that records issued books however I have no table for returned so unless I added a calculated field that counts the number of records for a particular book that has a return date less than today and assume that all books are returned on time I don't think I can do this. A'm I right?

Comment: I would have "isReturned" as boolean field in the "issued books" table. Then if someone returns a book, instead of increasing a dropdown box, mark the issue as returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first set the Combobox's [RowSourceType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835376.aspx) to "Value List", to determine the combobox list is to be manually managed. then you use a Combobox's [AddItem method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835377.aspx) method to add an item, and [RemoveItem Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198307.aspx) to remove an item. [This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998161/removing-all-items-from-a-combobox) how you remove all items:

```
For i = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount
   'Remove an item from the ListBox.
   ListBox1.RemoveItem 0
Next i
```

After removing all current items, calculate how many `Available Copies`, and add them to the list in a loop:

```
For i = 1 To AvailableCopies    
    'Add an item from the ListBox.
    ListBox1.AddItem i   
Next i
```

Run this code for each book record presented, probably on OnCurrent event of a form.

Comment: Thank you Marlan, you answered my original question very well however Andre pointed out that I don't actually need a drop down list.

Comment: @word4q, I haven't read the question as well as Andre... In my mind it seemed you wanted to allow a user borrow multiple copies of a book... I'll read more carefully next time, do my best of giving better assistance ;).