# How to fix " Run-time error '380' in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, search, listbox

I am adding more than 10 columns to my listbox in Excel VBA. I keep getting run-time error '380'-Invalid property value. It works properly until column 9 in listbox. I couldn`t find any proper solution for this anywhere else. Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

```
Private Sub txtSearch_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal 
Shift As Integer)
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("Lookup")
Dim rw
Dim strText As String
strText = LCase(txtSearch.Text)
With ListBox1
.RowSource = ""
.ColumnCount = 12

 For Each rw In rng.Rows
    If InStr(LCase(Cells(rw.Row, 4)), strText) Then
        .AddItem Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cells(rw.Row, 3).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cells(rw.Row, 4).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = Cells(rw.Row, 5).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = Cells(rw.Row, 6).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = Cells(rw.Row, 7).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = Cells(rw.Row, 8).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 8) = Cells(rw.Row, 9).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 9) = Cells(rw.Row, 10).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 10) = Cells(rw.Row, 11).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 11) = Cells(rw.Row, 12).Value
        .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 12) = Cells(rw.Row, 13).Value           
    End If
Next    

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Add the values to an array (arr) then set the `.List = arr`.  Without digging further, I would guess that it's an issue with the counting in your list.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu. Can you help me merge your idea with what was proposed by A Cohen please?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will fix everything, but it will definitely clean it up a bit.  Also, I am not sure what worksheet you are pulling `Cells(rw.Row, 2).value` from. But they may have something to do with why it stops part way through.  Also, to clean it up a bit, try an additional `For Statement`.

```
Private Sub txtSearch_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("Lookup")
    Dim rw
    Dim strText As String: strText = LCase(txtSearch.Text)

    With ListBox1
        .RowSource = ""
        .ColumnCount = 21

        For Each rw In rng.Rows
            If InStr(LCase(Cells(rw.Row, 4)), strText) Then
                .AddItem Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value
                For x = 1 To 12  '''Change Worksheet to your Worksheet name
                    .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, x) = Worksheets("Sample").Cells(rw.Row, x + 1).Value2
                Next x
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

If this doesn't help, try what @Cyril said with the array.

Comment: Thank you. Your code helped for cleaning it up. But I`m still getting errors. Can you help me on merging yours with what was proposed by @Cyril?

Comment: @FaridFarmani Are you sitll getting error 380 or something different?

Comment: I'm a bit confused at how to merge @Cyril's idea

Comment: I`m also working on it. If I can figure it out I`ll post my solution here.

Comment: @ACohen I added mine for this, so hopefully you can make sense of what I did... the explanation is at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1):

Just came back to you... a bit long, but here's the general thoughts...

This all goes in the code for the ActiveX Control:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim rw As Range, strtext As String
    Dim arr As Variant, ai As Long, aj As Long 
    Dim brr As Variant, bi As Long, bj As Long
    strtext = "a" 'I used this when i did my testing
    ReDim arr(11, 0)
    For Each rw In Range("rng")
        If InStr(LCase(rw.Value), strtext) Then
            aj = findaj(arr)
            If Not IsEmpty(arr(1, aj)) Then
                aj = aj + 1
                ReDim Preserve arr(11, aj)
            End If
            For ai = 1 To 11
                arr(ai, aj) = Cells(rw.Row, ai + 1).Value
            Next ai
        End If
    Next rw
    ReDim brr(aj, 11)
    For bi = 0 To aj
        For bj = 1 To 11
            brr(bi, bj) = arr(bj, bi)
        Next bj
    Next bi
    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 11
    ListBox1.List = brr
End Sub

Private Function findaj(ByVal brr As Variant)
    Dim j As Long, meow As String
    j = 0
    Do While True
        On Error GoTo toll
        j = j + 1
        meow = brr(1, j)
    Loop
toll:
    findaj = j - 1
End Function
```

So there's a lot going on here... I use two separate arrays, due to how redimming arrays works in VBA.  You can **only** update the second element of the array, so `arr(ai,aj)` can only have `aj` updated when I `redim preserve` while adding a new row to my array.

So we make an array (`arr`) that captures the data based on VBA's limitations.  Within that array, we use a function, `findaj`, which intentionally traps an error to determine the appropriate last *column* in `arr` (i italicized the use of column, as it's not truly the case, but it makes sense spatially when thinking about it).

You then convert the array `arr` to `brr` in the appropriate order of columns/rows.

Afterwards, you make your `.list = brr`.

Comment: Thank you for your code and the descriptions. I tried the code but I keep getting 'run-time error '70'- Permission denied' on "ListBox1.List = brr". It also takes a while after I type my first letter of the whole searching word. Did you get this error at any time?

Comment: @FaridFarmani I did not; I ensured that I have MSForms 2.0 library turned on in my references, though i don't think that would deny permission.  Is your listbox locked?

Comment: @Cyril - This is well above my expertise, sorry if I don't follow.

Comment: @Cyril I checked MSForms and the listbox and everything is normal. Not sure what the issue is here. Is there any chance we can do the job using Autofilter method?

Comment: @FaridFarmani See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43350502/3233363  This may be under the same pretense, where you need to `ListBox1.RemoveItem`.  I apologize for missing that; my ListBox knowledge comes from userForms, where this is generated on Initialize, not being re-written.  This will lead to a solution to removing items: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998231/3233363 (says combobox in the title, but the answer is about listbox)