# Run-Time Errors 380 and 381 generated when searching for a word in a Listbox through a textbox on a Userform

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, excel-2013

I want to search for a word in a ListBox that has data drawn from a worksheet.

A video on YouTube [Advance Multi column Search in Listbox with Single Textboxt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuOYQASY3p4), describes code to search in a ListBox for a keyword typed into a Textbox on the same Userform.

It works for a data set of 6 columns. When I change the code and corresponding control properties for a data set of 11 columns, the code throws

> Run-Time Errors 380 and 381

in the two For... Next loops.

I am using Excel 2013 on Windows 10.

```vb
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()

    With Me.ListBox2
        .Clear
        For ColHead = 1 To 11
            .AddItem
            .List(0, ColHead - 1) = Sheet2.Cells(1, ColHead).Value  '<<< 'Run-Time Error 380, Invalid Property Value
        Next ColHead
        
        ' If I comment out the For... Next loop above the code runs up to the next For... Next loop below _
      and there it throws up run-time error 381. I have marked it there with a comment.

        ListRow = 1
        If IsDate(Me.TextBox2) Then
            FindVal = CDate(Me.TextBox2)
        ElseIf IsNumeric(Me.TextBox2) Then FindVal = Val(Me.TextBox2)
        Else
            FindVal = "*" & Me.TextBox2 & "*"
        End If
        LastRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For ShRow = 2 To LastRow
            FindRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Rows(ShRow).EntireRow, FindVal)
            If FindRow > 0 Then
                For ListCol = 1 To 11
                    .AddItem
                    .List(ListRow, ListCol - 1) = Sheet2.Cells(ShRow, ListCol).Value '<<< 'Run-Time Error 381, Invalid Property Value
                Next ListCol
                ListRow = ListRow + 1
            End If
        Next ShRow
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I wanted to upload an Excel file that has the error generating code I have described above, but I don't know how to do it. Will someone please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: This post looks like it should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672570/how-to-fix-run-time-error-380-in-excel-vba

Comment: Thank you user10186832. Using the code from the link you shared only sets up the column headers in the Listbox. It does not work for the keyword search part of the code, which still throws up Run-time Error 380.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit of 10 columns if you use unbound data sources for a listbox:

From the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/columncount-property?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(fm20.chm2000940)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue):

> Setting ColumnCount to 0 displays zero columns, and setting it to -1 displays all the available columns. **For an unbound data source, there is a 10-column limit (0 to 9).**

**Update**: There are two ways to fill a listbox:
The first is to assign a Range to the listbox (the property is called `RowSouce`). With that, you can have more than 10 columns, and you can have a header row. This is called "bound" data source (because the listbox data is bound to a range).
The second is to fill the list manually (as you do), by calling `AddItem` for every row you want to display. As the data is not bound to anything, this is called "unbound", and for whatever reason there are a max of 10 columns supported (0..9) and you can't have a header row.

The property `BoundColumn` defines which column is seen as "value". If you define 1 as boundColumn and check the `value`-property of the listbox (eg in a change event), the value of the first column of the selected row is used. This is true for bound and unbound lists.

Comment: Thank you, FunThomas, for your reply. I am afraid I know nothing about bound and unbound data sources. The properties settings for listbox on my userform only has a BoundColumn value set to the default value 1. I found that setting the ColumnCount to -1 in Properties, as you advised, displays only 10 column heads though the ColumnCount is set to 11. What should I do now?

Comment: Thank you so much, FunThomas, for being patient with me and taking the time to explain bound and unbound data sources. I have understood it very well now. I shall forever be grateful to you for this. 
I set the ColumnCount as -1 and set the column count in the code to 9 instead of 11, The code now works like a charm. Thank you so much. You have solved my problem.